# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting rows based on color adjacent

Tags: microsoft-excel, formulas, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets to make a homework spreadsheet and have used conditional formatting to arrange assignments by the due date and also each class has a color. When I type in a class it automatically changes the cell to the class color but I want the rest of the row to be a pastel version of the class color. I am now trying to figure out how to automatically change the color of cells C3 - F3 in relation to the color of cell B3. Is there any way to do this? [Image shows my spreadsheet set up and how different classes have different colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSHRq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an $ to fix the column letter, you can use conditional formatting to apply to the entire row based on a single column (or the other way around, if you fix the row number and base it on the top row values).

So, if I want the rows in columns B to E to change colour if the value in the A column is 1, I would use the condition **=$A1=1** for cells B:E.

[image: google sheets: conditional formatting of subsequent columns]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, my column doesn't have numerical values but text so I don't think that would work. I attempted to use an (=IF($A1="name of class") but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Text also works! I added a screenshot based on yours, have a look. Use quotation marks around the text string. You can also make this thing more dynamic by making these formulas refer to a separate list of class names, that way you don't have to alter the conditional formats every semester.